# for any subset S of finite group G and any g,h∈G, show |gSh|=|S|

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, order-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group.  For any subset $S$ of $G$, and any group elements $g,h \in G$, I want to show that $|gSh|=|S|$, i.e. that the cardinality of $S$ is preserved when multiplying on the left and on the right.

My attempt:

$$ S = g^{-1}(gSh)h^{-1} \subseteq (gSh) \subseteq S $$

Am i right? If not, how can i prove the statement?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  This site allows you to write mathematical formulas and equations using $\LaTeX$ markup.  See this [FAQ and tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on the MathJax software that enables this.

Comment: I don't think that is actually true. For example let $G = S_{3}$, $S = A_{3}$, $h = (123)$ and $g = (12)$. $gA_{3}h = gA_{3} = S_{3}$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the inclusion $gSh\subset S$ does not hold in general.

However, you can define a map $f_{g,h}:G\to G$ by $s\mapsto gsh$, and show that it is bijective. For that,it may be helpful to notice that this map is the composition of $s\mapsto gs$ and $s\mapsto sh$.

Comment: Note that I may have unintentionally simplified the OP in making it coherent/editing.  Your observation proves the cardinality claim without using the hypothesis that $G$ is a finite group.